# Show data and radio button and save selected value of radio button with data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Hi have a data base as below the data is fetching is From PHP is Working but have a problem need to show radio button against all **StudentFirstName** as shown below and send back the data to another Table database of respective selected radio button value. on button click  register Id can be used as primary key to store in database.

Database

```
 SchoolID   StudentRegID    StudentFirstName StudCourse   StudentSection 
    FT001     12KQC31085        ABC             BCOM             A
    FT001     12KQC31086        DEF             BCOM             A        
    FT001     12KQC31087        GHI             BCOM             A  
    FT001     12KQC31088        JKL             BCOM             A
```

Database

```
 SchoolID   StudentRegID    StudentFirstName StudCourse   StudentSection  Status
    FT001     12KQC31085        ABC             BCOM             A        Absent
    FT001     12KQC31086        DEF             BCOM             A        Leave        
    FT001     12KQC31087        GHI             BCOM             A        Absent  
    FT001     12KQC31088        JKL             BCOM             A        Present
```

PHP Script

```
$mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','Uname','Pass','Database');

       //data from ajax
$standard1 = trim($_POST["tclass"]);
$section1 = trim($_POST["tsection"]);
$SchoolID1 = trim($_POST["tschoolid"]);

$query3="SELECT * FROM euser_student  WHERE  StudCourse='$standard1' and SchoolID='$SchoolID1'and StudentSection='$section1' order by StudentFirstName   ASC";
$data3=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query3)or die(mysqli_error());

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data3)){
    $dat3 = $row['StudentFirstName'];

    echo "<table><tr><td>"$dat3."</td></tr><table>";
}
```

3. Expecting out Put

   ```
               ABC         O Present   O Absent    O Leave
               DEF         O Present   O Absent    O Leave
               GHI         O Present   O Absent    O Leave
               JKL         O Present   O Absent    O Leave
   ```

**3.** Send selected value

Answer (score 0):

`<table><tr><td>"$dat3."</td><td><input type="radio" name='si".$stydentregid."'  value="Present">Present</td><td><input type="radio" name='si".$stydentregid."' value="Absent">Leave </td><td><input type="radio" name='si".$stydentregid."' value="Leave">Absent</td></tr><table>`While creating table column create above.  On submission fetch value of list of radio-button.

Comment: if i crate like that then how can i save data of multiple students i mean Values

Comment: You can just enclose the table to a form on whose submit you will get checkbox name as student id with 'st'(as appended manualy) prefix and their value.

Comment: This works perfect to fetch information, however, imagine, it has selected the leave radio button for a student, how will this radio information choose against that student goes and saves in the existing database table ? have you mentioned this in your code ? if yes can you point it for me please ?

Comment: for name of radio button, "$stydentregid" is being used which will be posted as key and it's value will carry present, absent or  leave whichever will be selected. Note: st has been prefixed to name of radio button make sure to take care of that, And add student registration id in your select query for ($stydentregid)... This is same as @Dot net learner answer

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how to make this possible with checkboxes, the same you can avail with radio buttons.

You can add input tag as below to your php page where data is display

```
echo "<input id="students_" name="students[]" type="radio" value="**UniqueID**"><table><tr><td>"$dat3."</td></tr><table>";
```

Then in your another php file where you have code to check submitted students, add following

```
$students = $_REQUEST['students'];
foreach ($gextras as $val) 
{
//Do the database code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not PHP Developer but I can give you Logic to store Data
You can generate table html Like This

```
 <table>
    <tr>
         <td>student Name</td>
          <td><input type="radio" value="p" id="StudentRegID_P" name="StudentRegID"><label for="StudentRegID_P" >Present<label/></td>
          <td><input type="radio" value="a" id="StudentRegID_A" name="StudentRegID"><label for="StudentRegID_A" >Absent<label/></td>
          <td><input type="radio" value="l" id="StudentRegID_L" name="StudentRegID"><label for="StudentRegID_P" >Leave<label/></td>
    </tr>
 <table>
```

In which "StudentRegID" is your Actual School Registration Id from Database.

So when user select Selection and Postback Data you will get selection of User with StudentRegID as key and Selection as Value  in Request Form.

Comment: @ShaikAsif , Check my answer it have all you need.

Comment: I think you are looping through Rows so you can generate string and echo it. I  give you sample Row in my answer